# search by filename in a specific repository with github api

Tags: github-api

I am developing a search similar to [github's repository file search](https://help.github.com/articles/finding-files-on-github/)
I don't understand why this query returns 1 result (a file named `headless.ts` exists in the repository):

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/code/?q=in:path+filename:headless+repo:rookout/explorook
```

While this query returns 0 results:

```
curl https://api.github.com/search/code/?q=in:path+filename:headles+repo:rookout/explorook
```

Notice I only removed one 's' from 'headless'
Can I not search for a file without specifing it's entire name?